# How to POST submit button through python requests?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy, python-requests

I logged in to this website by sending login and password through `POST`.

I don't need to pass all form data, just to click submit button visible as "zapisz zmiany".

Is it possible with `requests` or `scrapy` libraries?

[image: Button's HTML]

Comment: you can do that with headless browser like selenium

Comment: Use `selenium` to do browser automation, `requests` is not powerful enough most of the time.

Comment: I wish I could bypass selenium, running this with python's `requests` would be much easier on my server

Comment: python `requests` only call to the address and return the response, it don't interact with the website site itself

Comment: Using Scrapy, the right approach is described in https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Scrapy `FormRequest.from_response()` (but there is no guarantee that it will work because your page may use JavaScript):

```
yield scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
    response=response,
    formname="your_form_name", # you can get it from DevTools in your browser
    formdata={
        "form_field_1": "value_1", # you can get fields / values from the Network tab in DevTools (after you submit your form)
    },
    callback=self.parse_form, # a code that will process response
)
```